Why is my initial state which is a separate object being changed as well as state in react?
I have this as state in my component const [state, setState] = useState<IEmployee>(employeesInitialState)
And this is the code that is handling changes of that state
setState((prev: IEmployee) => {
        const copy = { ...prev }
        copy.contact[name[1]] = value
        return copy
      })

The problem is that it somehow changes not only the state but also employeesInitialState object that I use just to initially fill the state. That object is in a separate file and is just a constant that I am exporting and for some reason it is getting changed.

Hi, In line with the answer from @AKX, this post may also help you :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78974612/react-parent-prop-with-nested-array-is-mutated-by-spread-copied-state-variable/78977327#78977327

You're making a shallow copy and mutating an internal object.
setState((prev: IEmployee) => {
  return { ...prev, contact: { ...prev.contact, [name[1]]: value } };
});

to shallowly copy contact too and only modify the single value from the copied contact.
In non-React terms:
> foo = {baz: {wah: "quux"}}
 {baz: {…}}
> foo2 = {...foo}
 {baz: {…}}
> foo2.baz.weh = "wooh"
 'wooh'
> foo.baz
 {wah: 'quux', weh: 'wooh'}  // foo.baz and foo2.baz are the same object so both were modified


There are libraries such as Mutative to make this sort of immutable modification more convenient.
